# Resting heart rate is 40

Tags: heart-rate

I'm not an athlete and definitely don't think I'm fit, I do exercise every now then. my RHR is about 40 and sometimes it goes as low as 38. I used to be able to run a 5k without stopping but I do feel tired now and feel like can't get enough air while running but maybe it's because I'm not as fit as I used to be. 
Two years ago I had an ECG done for 24 hours cause the Dr said my heartbeat was very slow and wanted to make use there is nothing wrong with my heart but ECG result came back normal and I was told my RHR in that 24 hrs was 41 bpm but everything was normal. However I'm just a bit worried now as feel very tired and feel I have no energy even though I eat enough food. my question is could I have Bradycardia despite the normal result of the ECG?  shall I ask my GP to refer me to a cardiologist? 
just some more info I'm female, 33, my height is 164cm and my weight is 55kg

Comment: It is possible for you to have an ECG with no rhythm issues but have rate issues. Anything under 60 beats per minute is considered bradycardia and yes, if you are tired and not feeling well, this is probably a good time to pay your doctor a visit and possibly a cardiologist.

Comment: I would see your Dr about no energy.   You can also ask to be referred to a cardiologist.

Comment: Bradycardia is just a fancy term for a heart rate slower than 60. Many people have this with otherwise normal ECG's.